# limit the number of results returned from server

Tags: python, python-ldap

I am using `python-ldap` in order to retrieve data about users. The servers limit is set to 100,000 and I can't change this value.

I am looking for a way to limit the number of results the server returns, **This must be dont on the server side and not using python**. I tried using [opt.sizelimit](https://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html#ldap.OPT_SIZELIMIT) but for some reason this doesn't work.

code:

```
l = ldap.initialize(g_url)
try:
    l.protocol_version = g_protocol_version
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_SIZELIMIT, 3)
    l.simple_bind_s(g_username, g_password)
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? what can be done? are there any known problem with this feature?

I saw [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail//python-ldap/2011q4/003026.html) answer, I am looking for an easier method (hopefully using the above option)

Comment: What is difficult about the [linked method](https://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap-resiter.html)?

Comment: I want to retrieve exact number of events.

Comment: Use [**`islice`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)